# Task does not stop in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-4

I can't figure out why a task in Gulp starts but doesn't end automatically
**The task code is as follows:**

```
import del from 'del';
import { projectFolder } from '../config';

const cleanRoot = () => {
  return del(projectFolder);
};

export default cleanRoot;
```

**I run the command and like this it is written in the console:**

```
C:\Users\sy\Desktop\temp>npm run clean
> project-name@1.0.0 clean
> gulp cleanRoot
[16:07:34] Requiring external module @babel/register
[16:07:39] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\temp\gulpfile.babel.js
[16:07:39] Starting 'cleanRoot'...
[16:07:39] Finished 'cleanRoot' after 60 ms
```

And everything after `Finished` hangs the cursor on the next line and nothing happens :)

Comment: Have you tried `return del(projectFolder, { force: true });`? The option `force` is required when deleting something outside the current directory.

Comment: @GOTO0
Now I tried it 3 times, nothing came of it :(. The funny thing is that this is + – on all tasks, and it is not clear why.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating gulp tasks, gulp injects callback as a first argument of your task function that will notify gulp that your task has ended.

```js
const cleanRoot = (cb) => {
  del(projectFolder);
  cb();
};
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't help :(.  
I have already tried this option.  
Here is a screenshot showing that nothing is working - https://ibb.co/Qfm82Mn.

Comment: I have to press the combination `ctrl + c` to get out of this

Comment: Of what tasks your npm clean command consist of? Could you post your clean task code?

Comment: @Terminant
`"clean": "gulp cleanRoot"`. This command just starts the given task.

Comment: is `del` method asynchronous?

Comment: @Terminant I honestly don't know how to do it via `async`. I tried to do as it is written in the instructions for the `del` module, but nothing came of it.

Comment: Could you try something like, `del(projectFolder).then(() => { cb() })`

Comment: @Terminant Nope, it doesn't work :(. This is a damn assembly. Maybe something is preventing me from completing the task, but what I can't figure out...